# Customizable multiple Mootools file uploader

Tags: javascript, url, file-upload, mootools

Can you recommend me customizable file uploader on top of Mootools? It whould be greate, if I can bind to 'addFile', 'uploadFile', 'uploadAllFiles' events, customize CSS and templates.

Other important is that we want to make image transloading by URL, but we do not want to hack libraries at many places.

Comment: go to the mootools forge and look? eg, plugin from @tbela99 is rather good. this is not a code issue, though...

Answer (score 0):

Not for moo tools but worth mentioning would be plupload…

http://www.plupload.com/

Being standalone, you'll be able to update it way easier and i guess for a javascript file uploader, it's worth the extra kbs !